# How to populate a QListView with value and display data?

Tags: python, pyqt, qlistview, qstandarditemmodel, qstandarditem

I'm doing a form that contains a QListView. It's populated from database with this code:

```
model = QStandardItemModel(self.listUser)
for row in self.SELECT_USERS_ACCOUNTS():
    item = QStandardItem(str(row[1]))
    model.appendRow(item)
self.listUser.setModel(model)
```

My QListView is named listUser and SELECT_USERS_ACCOUNTS() function returns data created by select id,name from table_user, I need to store row[0] (id column in the table_user) too because when the user will click an item into the QListView. I want to capture this Id. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In QStandardItem data for different roles can be stored by `setData(data, role)`.
Stored data are returned by `data(role)`.

Roles >= 256 (0x100) are UserRoles, see [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum)

so you can store the id by

```
item.setData(row[0],256)
```

and ask it by

```
item.data(256)
```

edit 31.03.2015:

```
for row in self.SELECT_USERS_ACCOUNTS():
    item = QStandardItem(str(row[1]))
    # add userData to item
    item.setData(row[0],256)
    # item.setData(row[2], 257) and so on if there are further columns in row
    model.appendRow(item)

self.listUser.setModel(model)
self.listUser.clicked.connect(self.getUserData)

def getUserData(self,index):
    item = self.model().item(index.row(),index.column())
    iId = item.data(256)
    # xyz = item.data(257) for further columns
    print(iId) # or do anything else
```

Comment: I'm new in pyqt, please how can I change my code, thanks in advance.